# Trouble with Input Box range attribution

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to build a utility that allows the user to select formulas in a column (or row) and transpose those to a row (or column) using the `Transpose` method of `PasteSpecial`.  I have it working for with a specific target cell, but as soon as I try to give the user control over what cell is targetted I receive a Run-time error 1004 "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".

Here is the working code (assuming that none of the selected formulas are in `Range("E3")`:

```
Dim rSelection As Range
    Set rSelection = Selection

Call MakeSelectionAbsolute(rSelection)
rSelection.Copy

Dim rMoveTo As Range
    Set rMoveTo = Range("E3")


With rMoveTo
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                   False, Transpose:=True
    Call MakeSelectionRelative(Selection)
End With
rSelection.Delete
```

I have tried several methods (including a UDF that would return the value), but I think the problem stems from using an Input Box for this.  My current attempt was to replace `Set rMoveTo = Range("E3")` with this:

```
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set rMoveTo = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
               "Select the first cell of the range you want to transpose to.", _
                    Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
```

To my eye, such a substitution should work. I tried adding a watch on rMoveTo and it looked like it appropriately set a value for the cell I selected (but I'll admit that I don't yet understand how to read all the watch data produced for a range).

The Run-tim error 1004 occurs at `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True`

Why is this method is not working and how can it be fixed?  It seems likely to be something simple, but I'm at a loss for what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipboard is very sensitive to UI operations. When you select range using `Application.InputBox` clipboard is clearing and `PasteSpecial` fails because there is nothing to paste.

Change the order of your operations: first select range, and then copy/paste:

```
Dim rSelection As Range
Set rSelection = Selection

Call MakeSelectionAbsolute(rSelection)

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set rMoveTo = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
           "Select the first cell of the range you want to transpose to.", _
                title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
'if user select nothing - exit sub
If rMoveTo Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'copy AFTER user select range
rSelection.Copy

With rMoveTo
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                   False, Transpose:=True
    Call MakeSelectionRelative(Selection)
End With
rSelection.Delete
```

Comment: Brilliant. You are exactly right: moving the `.Copy` operation to just before the `.PasteSpecial` operation solved the issue. Thanks!